# Redirect in React Router 5 is successfully redirecting, but not rendering the child component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have changed the routes in my app, and in case any users have bookmarked urls to the old routes I have added some redirects to the new routes. Most of them are working fine, however this one is not -

**App.tsx**

```
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import Routes from './Routes';
import history from './history';

const App: FunctionComponent = () => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <Routes />
  </Router>
);

export default App;
```

**RouteSwitch.txs**

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const RouteSwitch: FunctionComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Redirect exact from="/documents" to="/documents/list" />
      <Route exact path="/documents/list">
        <DocumentsContainer />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default RouteSwitch;
```

The redirect from `/documents` to `/documents/list` works, however the `DocumentsContainer` does not get rendered. If I directly request `/documents/list` then it renders fine. It's as if `<Switch>` finds its first match (the Redirect) and then decides its job is done. I tried adding the `push` prop to the Redirect but it didn't make a difference.

My example is very similar to the one given on the React Training site - https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect/from-string

Thoughts?

Comment: How can we help you without code? .. this link can be useful for us: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Apologies, this is my first question to SO and discovered that hitting enter in the Tags field causes the question to be submitted prematurely

Comment: ```<Route exact path="/documents/list" component={DocumentsContainer} />```.  Can this code help you?

Comment: Good suggestion, however that is giving the same behaviour

Comment: I tried this alternate approach for the redirect but it still behaves the same - `<Route exact path="/documents" render={() => <Redirect to="/documents/list" />} />`

Comment: Mystery solved. The DocumentsContainer **was** rendering, except by some quirk (yet to be figured out) none of its content was displayed. My lesson . . . avoid assumptions! (though I had done a quick check of the React Tools component tree earlier and didn't see it)

Comment: It's nice if you add yourself a complete answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - the `DocumentsContainer` component was *actually* rendering, but just not showing anything due to a quirk with how the use of the redirect was causing a loader count to be incremented by one (but not decremented) resulting in the loader count not returning to 0 to allow document data to be loaded from Redux and the content to be rendered.